# If in Array on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two result from MYSQL...

```
$table = $db->getPrefix().'content';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT catid FROM $table WHERE id = $id");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$catId = $result['catid'];
```

And...

```
$table_2 = $db->getPrefix().'categories';
$query_2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM $table_2 WHERE parent_id = 11");
while($result_2 = mysql_fetch_array($query_2)){
echo implode(',',$result_2);
}
```

I need a if like this...

```
if($catId = $result_2){
...
}
```

How can I solve?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to accomplish?

Comment: You need to try this on your own or show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to find out if $catId is in the $result_2 array. If so, then you've already answered your question with your title here.. [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
if(in_array($catId,$result_2))
```